# how to make rtsp server with gstreamer for h.265

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp

I want to build a server with gstreamer that get *push RTSP*, encoded in *H.265* codec and audio in *AAC* format from multiple cameras. Also client should be able to pull RTSP streams from this servers
Could you add something to this code? or could you check if it is correct?

```sh
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc uri=udp://127.0.0.1:5000 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H265, payload=(int)96, seqnum-offset=(uint)27727, timestamp-offset=(uint)1713951204, ssrc=(uint)2573237941, a-framerate=(string)30" ! rtph265depay ! h265parse ! vaapidecode ! vaapipostproc ! vaapisink
```

[image: server diaram]

Comment: Some time ago I've implemented framework to solve the same task: https://github.com/RSATom/IpCamBox Unfortunately it's not in ready-to-production state and works only with h264 atm, but it works for me.

Comment: May be FastoCloud can help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Live 555 RTSP server 
http://www.live555.com/mediaServer/

You can also create a gstreamer plugin for the same.

Comment: live555 is not an option for this. it doesn't support receiving push h.265 rtsp. we tried

Comment: please check this link : https://live-devel.live.narkive.com/ByeTRjsH/live555-now-supports-streaming-transmitting-and-receiving-h-265-rtp-streams